# Ruby detect if webserver is running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Ruby with dashing and wish t report the status of a few flask webservers that are running on various ports on a couple of machines.

http://example.url.ltd:5009
http://example.urltwo.ltd:5007

Any ideas?

I've tried the net/http library but with no luck.

```
begin
    uri = URI.parse("#{host}:#{port}")
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/ping?")

    response = http.request(request)
    return JSON.parse(response.body)
rescue
    return
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: where do you want to report? is it in a webview or commandline? please be more descriptive.

Comment: Are the webservers on the same machine? Another machine? What did you try with net/http?

Comment: Why the `?` in `/ping?`  ? Does it exist/return valid JSON? Maybe try inspecting response.body. Additionally if you're trying to figure out what's going on, divide and conquer with some well-placed `puts` to figure out where it dies. (hint: `puts "error"` in your rescue block, and between the request/return)

Comment: In Ruby the `return` is implicit if you're doing it as the last operation. It's sufficient to have `JSON.parse(...)` as your last line. Doing a blind rescue here is also a bad idea, you may have an error in your code. Try and trap only those exceptions you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You will be go with gem [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) for the curl calling in ruby

And **require 'curb'** in the class:

```
begin     
   response = Curl::Easy.perform("http://www.google.co.uk")
   return JSON.parse(response.body)
rescue
    return
end
```

There is many way to try this.